# Ошибка в сниффере: 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: delphi

Я писал софт, у меня начали сыпатся только ошибки. Софт - брут. Начал просматривать запросы через сниффер и при запросах выдаёт ошибку "**400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port**" что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что порт, на который ты отправляешь HTTP запрос работает по HTTPS. Измени запрос для работы по https или не пиши бруты, ибо это не есть хорошо=)

---

Или тебе нужно правильно (по особому) общаться с этим портом, или ты неправильно делаешь запрос.